# Image gradient in the point

Tags: math, vector, gradient, point, image-segmentation

I'm working with the image segmentation. I need to compute image gradient in the point, so I was trying to understand by myself (because I know how to calculate gradient when having an ordinary equation) but I failed. I was googling... and googling but to find wright answer I couldn't.

Can anyone say or give some information how to compute image gradient in the point step by step?

Comment: Tai va kaip tu čia dirbi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gradient at each pixel of an image `I(x, y)` is simply the 2D vector `(dI/dx,dI/dy)(x, y)`. Approximate `dI/dx` and `dI/dy` with centered finite difference:

```
dI/dx(x, y) = (I(x + 1, y) - I(x - 1, y)) / 2 = (I(x + 1, y) - I(x, y) + I(x, y) - I(x - 1, y)) / 2
dI/dy(x, y) = (I(x, y + 1) - I(x, y - 1)) / 2 = (I(x, y + 1) - I(x, y) + I(x, y) - I(x, y - 1)) / 2
```

Comment: But does I(x, y) have any equation?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas No, given the context, I(x, y) does not have any equation. I(x, y) is simply the sample value at pixel (x, y). This is why its partial derivatives have to be approximated using neighboring pixels. Also note that image processing operations are usually defined for greyscale images only, although there are ways to generalize them for color images.

Comment: so grad I(x, y) is a vector, right? If it is a vector, whose direction does it show?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas Yes, the gradient at each pixel is a 2D vector and it's pointing in the direction of highest intensity increase. To see why, go back to the definition of the gradient of a function: f(x + hx, y + hy) = f(x, y) + < grad f(x, y), (hx, hy) > + o(...). You get the largest f(x + hx, y + hy) when (hx, hy) is collinear with the gradient of f at (x, y). Hence the gradient points in the direction of highest increase of f.

Comment: Let us think, that I have the 3x3 size of pixels image. I get the vectors of these pixels ([link to the image](http://oi41.tinypic.com/o8h2r9.jpg)). So grad I(x,y) is pointing to the neighbour pixel with the highest intensity increase, right?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas First, in your 3x3 example, you can only apply the formulas I've given for the center pixel (the one at the boundaries would need boundary conditions). If you apply the formulas, you get for this center pixel (dI/dx,dI/dy)=(1-4,1-5)/2=(-3,-4)/2=(-1.5,-2). And indeed the highest intensity values around the center pixel are more to the left and to the top of this pixel. Note that the formulas I've given do not use the diagonal neighbors, so it's just luck that the gradient is pointing to 10.

Comment: Ohh, I made mistake. Now I have the proper image ([link](http://oi39.tinypic.com/2a8m1xj.jpg)). I hope the last one question: from the vector we can say that arrows directs not only to '10' but also to '7' (because they are the highiest), right?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas For me the positive x axis goes to the right and the positive y axis goes down. As a result, the gradient at the center pixel (-1.5, -2) points towards 10 (left and up).

Comment: In Lithuania the positive x axis goes to the right and the positive y axis goes up :D I made the table according to you ([link](http://oi44.tinypic.com/25un0p5.jpg)). So I'm right when I'm saying that table show the two highiest points in the table?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas Yes and no. The finite differences formulas I gave use only left/right and up/down neighbors, not the diagonal ones. So as I wrote previously, it's just luck that the gradient happens to be pointing towards 10. If you replace the value 10 in your image, the gradient would still be pointing in this direction. It's pointing in this direction because of 4 and 5.

Comment: So what is the best to use?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas The formula I gave is typically used. The interpretation of the gradient comes from the continuous case, so it always has to be adapted to the discrete case, depending on how the transition from the continuous world to the discrete one was made.